# Android repo tool `repo update` without Gerrit

Tags: git, gitlab, repo

We are using the Android repo tool for our own non-Android software.  We are using GitLab, **not Gerrit** for code review.  With GitLab, I only need to do an ordinary push of the topic branch, as if I had done `git push` in each repository of my workspace.

How do I make `repo upload`  do an ordinary `git push` on multiple repositories?    You might say that I need the nonexistent `repo push` command.

I tried to realize this using various values for the `<remote review />` attribute in the manifest file, such as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest>

  <remote  name="wfe"
           alias="origin"
           review="origin"
           fetch=".." />
  <remote  name="wcore"
           alias="origin"
           review="ssh://git@gitlabserver:sw/wcore"
           fetch=".." />
  <default revision="master"
           remote="wfe"
           sync-j="4" />

  <project path="wcore" name="wcore" remote="wcore" groups="sdk" />
  <project path="wfe" name="wfe" groups="sdk" />

</manifest>
```

However, I get errors like:

```
repo upload

----------------------------------------------------------------------
[FAILED] wcore/          repo-test      
       (ssh://git@gitlabserver:sw/wcore: <urlopen error [Errno 110] Connection timed out>)
[FAILED] wfe/            repo-test      
       (origin: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I enhanced the [Android repo tool with a `repo push` command](https://github.com/wavecomp/git-repo) that does exactly this.  Also, it performs the pushes in the order declared in the manifest file.

We have been successfully using it in production for quite a while now.